# View order changes when I limit number results

Tags: views

This is really weird. I have a View of nodes like so:

Node 1
Node 2
Node 3

When I limit the number of results to 1, instead of the first result 'Node 1' showing, I'm getting the last one 'Node 3'.

My View is a clone of the system View "A view to emulate Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term.". Its an attachment display that is having this issue.

My View is too large to post here, but below is the attachment in question:

```
/* Display: Attachment 4 */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'Attachment 4', 'attachment_4');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Promotional Text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['id'] = 'field_shared_promo_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['table'] = 'field_data_field_shared_promo_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['field'] = 'field_shared_promo_text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_shared_promo_text']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Video Thumbnail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['id'] = 'field_video_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['table'] = 'field_data_field_video_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['field'] = 'field_video_thumbnail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_video_thumbnail']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '[field_shared_promo_text]
[field_video_thumbnail]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'video' => 'video',
);
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page_3' => 'page_3',
  'default' => 0,
  'page' => 0,
  'page_1' => 0,
  'page_2' => 0,
  'page_4' => 0,
  'page_5' => 0,
);
$translatables['show_sub_category_pages'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('All'),
  t('Page'),
  t('Print and make'),
  t('Print & Make'),
  t('<div class="border1">
 <div class="border1-inner">
  [field_shared_promo_image]
  <div class="border1-text">[field_shared_promo_text]</div>
 </div>
</div>'),
  t('Feed'),
  t('Print and colour'),
  t('Print & Colour'),
  t('<div class="border1">
<div class="border1-inner">
[field_shared_promo_image]
<div class="border1-text">[field_shared_promo_text]</div>
</div>
</div>'),
  t('Page 2'),
  t('Pictures & Wallpaper'),
  t('Pictures & Wallpapers'),
  t('Page 3'),
  t('Videos'),
  t('<div class="border1">
<div class="border1-inner">
<div class="border1-text">[field_shared_promo_text]</div>
[field_video_thumbnail]
</div>
</div>'),
  t('Page 4'),
  t('Games'),
  t('<div class="border1">
 <div class="border1-inner">
  <div class="border1-text">[field_shared_promo_text]</div>
  [field_shared_promo_image]
</div>
</div>'),
  t('Attachment'),
  t('Print + make, print + colour attachment. '),
  t('Attachment 2'),
  t('Pictures attachment '),
  t('<div class="showInfoImgCont">
  [field_shared_promo_image]
</div>'),
  t('Characters'),
  t('About the Show'),
  t('<div class="border1">
 <div class="border1-inner">
  <div class="border1-text">[field_shared_promo_text]</div>
  [field_shared_promo_image]
 </div>
</div>'),
  t('Attachment 4'),
  t('[field_shared_promo_text]
[field_video_thumbnail]'),
);
```

Comment: I think this is related to sort critirea  options

Comment: As a hack ive reversed the sort order. But this shouldnt be necessary. If I have multiple results in a view and then I just change the number of results to 1, then the first result should be shown.